# How to find the largest ellipsoid which fits within a convex hull?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry, convex-hulls, ellipsoids

I am looking for a mathematical realization of finding the largest ellipsoid which fits within a convex hull. Let's say the ellipsoid is defined as

$$ E = \left\{ By+d \mid \left \| y \right \|_2\ \leq 1 \right\} $$

where $d$ is the center of the ellipsoid. For a given set of points, corresponding convex hull can be calculated in H-Ref (hyperplane representation), i.e., $Ax \leq b$. Thus, the idea is to find the ellipsoid which satisfied these two type of constraints minimizing the volume of the ellipsoid, i.e., $-\log(\det(A))$.

Here the problem is I still can't understand the way constraints set should be defined?

In other words,
[image]

Comment: You want to minimizes the volume?  Surely the infimum is 0 (because once you fit one you can always scale it by any factor $r\in(0,1)$) but is not achievable.

Comment: Downvoteers, please correct me something wrong, otherwise, why would I come here?

Comment: @user10354138 minimizing volume is one constraint but it should maximize the ellipsoid subject to Ax =b

Comment: Take a look at slide 10 of Boyd's [presentation](https://mathtube.org/sites/default/files/lecture-notes/Boyd_Stephen.pdf).

Comment: This has been addressed in Mathematica forum: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/234589/graph-construct-john-ellipsoids-circumscribing-and-inscribing-a-certain-3d-con/234796?noredirect=1#comment593239_234796  Also, see the PF link for additional info.  The method is convex Optimization.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thank you so much, that's what I was looking for

Comment: @GPrathap Knowing what you know now, please consider rewriting your question and answering it by posting a print-screen of Boyd's slide.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo sure thanks I will do, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Note: thanks to @RodrigodeAzevedo and @ Dominic for sharing valuable information.
The answer is based on [this](https://mathtube.org/sites/default/files/lecture-notes/Boyd_Stephen.pdf)

Let's say you are given a set of inequalities that describes by a polytope:

\begin{equation}
    P = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid a_i^Tx \leq b_i, \; i=1,...,m\}
\end{equation} So intention is to find inscribed ellipsoid with maximum volume. Let $\varepsilon$ be the ellipsoid that is to be estimated:
\begin{equation}
    E = \{x \mid x = By + d, y \in \mathbb{R}^n, \left \| y \right \|_2 \leq 1, \; B= B^T \succ 0\}.
\end{equation} In order to maximize the volume, the condition $E \subseteq P$ should be satisfied; this condition can be formed as the following way as a set of inequalities:
\begin{equation}
  \left \| Ba_i \right \| + a_i^Td \leq b_i, \; i=0,...,m
\end{equation}

Now we are ready to find the inscribed ellipsoid.
\begin{equation}\label{max_volume}
\begin{aligned}
\min_{B,d} \quad & -\log \det(B)\\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad &\left \| Ba_i \right \| + a_i^Td \leq b_i, \; i=0,...,m \\
  & B \succeq 0\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

In python, this can be written as follows:

```
B = cp.Variable((dim,dim), PSD=True)
d = cp.Variable(dim)
constraints = [cp.norm(B@A[i],2)+A[i]@d<=b[i] for i in range(len(A))]
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(-cp.log_det(B)), constraints)
optval = prob.solve()
```

For example,

[image]